# Convert text of a DataTable cell into a hyperlink, then add it back to the DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to convert the text of a cell, into a hyperlink, but the result I'm getting is the following.

> System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell

Instead of www.google.ca

So there's no error, it's just the completely wrong text I'm expecting.

Here's my code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//code to populate dt, there's a column called "TEXT", which I would like to
//dynamically make into a hyperlink if the text has more than 250 characters

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows){
  if (dr["TEXT"].ToString().Length > 250){
    HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
    link.NavigateUrl = "www.google.ca";
    link.Text = "www.google.ca";

    TabelCell tc = new TableCell();
    tc.Controls.Add(link);

    dr["TEXT"] = tc;
  }
}
```

I also tried adding the HyperLink directly to the DataColumn

```
dr["TEXT"] = link;
```

But I just got the same result.

I'm binding the DataTable to a DataGrid

Comment: You are actually converting a HyperLink control to text and assigning it to a data field. DataTable is not supposed to contain controls. What exactly you want to do is not clear.

Comment: I would like to make the text of one of the cells, into a hyperlink.

Comment: How do you populate the cells/Table? Where is that code?

Answer (score 0):

You 'foreach' code need to be:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows){}
```

You forgot the ".Rows"

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the question I was asking.  I'm asking how can I make text into a hyperlink for a certain cell in the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell` in your data table cell is that this is what you get when you call `ToString()` on a `TableCell` object.
You can't use a data table to store reference type data like this.
You should store the navigate url in one column and the text in another column and use a [`HyperLinkColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your datagrid to show it as a HyperLink.